# Setting the space of first x tick (0) and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, space

I want the first x tick (0) nearer to the y axis. I tried setting xlim, but I don't want to have the first x tick where the axes are crossing. Like just half the space between the y axis and the first x tick.
I didn't find an solution, maybe you can help me.

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `plt.xlim(-0.05, 3.1)`. Change -0.05 to some smaller/larger value until you are satisfied

Comment: @Sheldore Does not work. The 0 tick starts at the point where y axis crosses the x axis. `plt.xlim(0.05, 3.1)` same result.

Comment: Does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [plt.margins](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html) to specify the margins for x and y axis spearately.

```
plt.margins(x=0.02)
```

[image]